# Free native/C++ profiler

Tags: windows, gratis, software-development, c++, offline

I'm looking for a C++ / native profiler as an alternative to [Windows Performance Toolkit (WPT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/) (consisting of WPR, WPA and XPerf). It should have the following attributes:

- free (gratis)
- Windows 10
- supports 64 bit applications
- works offline
- supports sampling
- is still under active development
- GUI for analysis of the data

Ideally it supports:

- instrumentation

I don't need:

- .NET profiling
- remote profiling
- GPU profiling

The following don't qualify:

- [Very sleepy](https://github.com/VerySleepy/verysleepy), because it's last updated in 2014
- [Proffy](http://www.pauldoo.com/proffy/), because it's last updated in 2016
- [MicroProfiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArtemGevorkyan.MicroProfilerx64x86), although nice, does not support sampling

Comment: Just curious: why not use the Windows Performance Toolkit?  Is it not free?

Comment: @markspace: it's not particularly bad :-) I'm using it. But sometimes, other people implement things way cooler than the MS stuff. For example dnSpy versus ILdasm.